# Pull Tag Value using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, tags, beautifulsoup

Can someone direct me as how to pull the value of a tag using BeautifulSoup? I read the documentation but had a hard time navigating through it.  For example, if I had:

```
<span title="Funstuff" class="thisClass">Fun Text</span>
```

How would I just pull "Funstuff" busing BeautifulSoup/Python?

Edit: I am using version 3.2.1

Comment: Is this BeautifulSoup 3 or BeautifulSoup 4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have something to identify the element you're looking for, and it's hard to tell what it is in this question.

For example, both of these will print out 'Funstuff' in BeautifulSoup 3. One looks for a span element and gets the title, another looks for spans with the given class. Many other valid ways to get to this point are possible.

```
import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup('<html><body><span title="Funstuff" class="thisClass">Fun Text</span></body></html>')
print soup.html.body.span['title']
print soup.find('span', {"class": "thisClass"})['title']
```

Comment: Question: my import statement for BeautifulSoup is:
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, CData

However, the above code only seems to work when I:
    import BeautifulSoup

Any idea why?

Comment: That's just Python. If you are doing a relative import (`from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`) then change the line from `soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(...` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(...`

See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html for more.

Answer (score 1):

A tags children are available via .contents
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children
In your case you can find the tag be using its  CSS class to extract the contents

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup('<span title="Funstuff" class="thisClass">Fun Text</span>')
soup.select('.thisClass')[0].contents[0]
```

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors  has all the details nevessary