# Website Scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping

Is it possible to retrieve the value

```
data-price="4.7056"
```

From the following html

```
 '<tr style="cursor:pointer;" class="percent_price_list price_list_content" data-count="500" data-price="4.7056">
                <td class="quick_list_count">500k</td>
                <td>£4.71</td>
                <td>£23.53</td>
            </tr>'
```

If so how should I go about doing this I know how to scrape information normally between two html tags but have no idea how to get what is mentioned above. I'm aware of the beautiful soup libary, would this be useful in this situation?

Comment: I need to know more about what language, platform or framework you are using. If Javascript is available a simple `element.getAttribute('data-price')` would work, but somehow I don't think you are using Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is, among other things, an HTML parser. The following should get you started:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<tr style="cursor:pointer;" class="percent_price_list price_list_content" data-count="500" data-price="4.7056">
                <td class="quick_list_count">500k</td>
                <td>£4.71</td>
                <td>£23.53</td>
            </tr>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for item in soup.find_all('tr', {'data-price': True}):
    print(item['data-price'])

# 4.7056
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, BeautifulSoup can achieve this, and is covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618433/pull-tag-value-using-beautifulsoup). You're trying to get the value of a tag, by the sounds of it.

Snippet from the other question:

`print soup.find('span', {"class":"thisClass"})['title']`

**EDIT:** Sorry for the code formatting, it's an issue with the mobile app.